# construct string like object from literal whose size is known at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, struct

Any one can help explain how the following constructor works,

```
class StringData {
  public:
    /**
     * Constructs a StringData explicitly, for the case of a literal whose size is known at
     * compile time.
     */
    struct LiteralTag {};
    template<size_t N>
    StringData( const char (&val)[N], LiteralTag )
        : _data(&val[0]), _size(N-1) {}

private:
    const char* _data;        // is not guaranted to be null terminated 
    mutable size_t _size;     // 'size' does not include the null terminator
}
```

why not just use this constructor?

```
StringData(const char *c):_data(c){}
```

The full source code can be found here: http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/1.7.1/stringdata_8h_source.html

Comment: Because that one doesn't set the size...

Comment: @chris I can add size easily to the second one. why not add _size = strlen(c); in the body? Is it necessary create such complicated constructor to overcome the size?

Comment: While a huge amount of assignments it will save a lot of time instead of `strlen` which should iterate through the end of every string

Comment: @JiuDong, It's not complicated at all once you pick up some knowledge about templates, so why not use the more efficient version that's just as straightforward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `StringData(const char *c):_data(c){}` you will not know the size, or will have to figure out the size using `strlen` at runtime. That won't work unless the char array is null-terminated (ends with char '\0').

With the template version the compiler will figure out the size of the array at compile time, and initialize the size member properly. The constructor accept a reference to a fix-size array, and the compiler will instantiate a matching constructor depending on the actual array (and size) you pass to the constructor. It all happens at compile time and is less prone to human error.